# "Class blade.compiler does not exist" after upgrading Laravel from 5.7 to 5.8

Tags: laravel

I upgraded my Laravel project from version 5.7 to 5.8. I fixed some packages but after successful upgrade i checked my Laravel project version, I got this error:

> Class blade.compiler does not exist

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/890

Comment: sorry ! that's not working for me......

Answer (score 4):

According to this issue: [Move directive initialization to the boot method](https://github.com/Elhebert/laravel-sri/pull/24)
youo need to change your **facades** aliases from **register** sector to **boot** initialization sectors...

Look your files in `/app/Providers/***Provider.php`

And change all register methods (with facedes) from `register()` to `boot()`

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserVehiclesProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot() {  ### <= OK HERE
        $this->app->singleton('UserVehicles', UserVehicles::class);
    }

    public function register() {  ### <= BAD WITH FACADES
        $this->app->singleton('UserVehicles', UserVehicles::class);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

OR You can do it in the right way like that (change **singleton** to **bind** method)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserVehiclesProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {}

    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('UserVehicles', function () { ### <= Use `bind` method
            return new \App\Services\UserVehicles();
        });
    }
}
```